# How to get by salesmanId Web API 2 controller in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

i just started trying to build api but i'm having trouble .how to make api get by SalesmanId on Web API 2 with controller asp.net c# based on this sql server database , please help [image: MyDatabase]

```
        // GET: api/Transaksi
        public IQueryable<PrbSalesOrderTable> GetPrbSalesOrderTables()
        {
            return db.PrbSalesOrderTables;
        }

        // GET: api/Transaksi/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(PrbSalesOrderTable))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetPrbSalesOrderTable(int id)
        {
            PrbSalesOrderTable prbSalesOrderTable = db.PrbSalesOrderTables.Find(id);
            if (prbSalesOrderTable == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(prbSalesOrderTable);
        }
```

Comment: what is exactly your problem?what errors are you getting?

Comment: Hi @Zulfa Assyfa, what is the error message? The `Find(id)` method could works as expected in my project. Could you please share your model design?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the PrbSalesOrderTable by SalesmanId.

You need to use another function of LINQ:

`prbSalesOrderTable  = await db.PrbSalesOrderTables.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.SalesmanId == id);`

As the function name, you get the first element that matches the SalesmanId.

It is an async function, so you need to change your function to the following:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetPrbSalesOrderTable (int id)
```